# Regex replace by group in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I am trying to using regex replace in C# although I am having some issues getting the pattern to align correctly. What I am looking to do is replace certain combinations as per the first 2 groups but not if it matches the pattern of the 3rd group. What I have so far is

```
 var pattern = @"(,)|(\[\{)|(^:\[[*]])";

 string NewLineValue = Regex.Replace(LineValue, pattern,Environment.NewLine);
```

Essentially I want to replace all comma's or `[{` combinations in a string but not if the comma appears within `[[]]` characters (e.g `[[1234,5678]]`)

Any help is much appreciated...

Comment: The character "^" when placed inside square brackets is used to make a *negated* character class. The way you used it, in the third group, will only mean that it's the beginning of the text.

Comment: Sounds like you wanted to parse a JSON file.....

Comment: An short input example and desired output could help. Also, in case you're not trying to parse a JSON file like @CamiloTerevinto guessed (you could have it easier, if you are), try using a negative lookahead. See: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto that is the end goal, however at the moment I am trying to put some of the entries into a readable format for the end user to determine what elements are required.... the line items in the file do not follow a consistent format either as they are activity log entries and change line by line.

Comment: @shwartz, thank you. would you be able to elaborate as to where the "^" symbol would need to be placed in order to ignore the "," if it appears within a [[x]] section? your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match and capture all substrings between `[[` and `]]` (to be restored in the resulting string) and then match `,` or `[{` in all other contexts to replace with a newline:

```
var pattern = @"(?s)(\[\[.*?]])|,|\[{";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, pattern, m => 
    m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : Environment.NewLine);
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?s)` - a `RegexOptions.Singleline` inline option
- `(\[\[.*?]])` - Group 1: `[[`, any 0+ chars, as few as possible, and then `]]`
- `|` - or
- `,` - a comma
- `|` - or
- `\[{` - `[{` substring.

If Group 1 matches (`m.Groups[1].Success`), the match is pasted back (`m.Groups[1].Value`), else, the match (`,` or `[{`) is replaced with a `Environment.NewLine`.